# onDataChange is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have .php file like this

```
... html / php code ...

<script>
  (function(){
    window.mypage.onDataChange(data);
   })();
</script>

...html / php code ...

<script>
  (function(){
    window.mypage.onDataChange = function(data){
             ...
            };
   })();
</script>
```

So as we can see, i am calling my function on page top, and describing this function in the bottom, but can't uderstand why i am getting

```
{"msg":"TypeError: window.mypage.onDataChange is not a function","url":"/","lineNumber":"137","browser":{"mozilla":"true","version":"19.0"}}
```

what can be wrong? when i am testing my script it's working perfectly without any errors in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your functions before you call them. With the way this is structured, it won't be doing so.

Either switch the order of your two blocks of code (the window.mypage.onDataChange = function ... needs to be above the calling of the function), or simply put your function call into an onload.

jQuery style example:

```
$(function(){
  window.mypage.onDataChange(data);
});

HTML / PHP Code
```

Working code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.mypage = {
    onDataChange: function(data){
     console.log(data);
    }
  }

  var data = "This is data, yay";
  window.mypage.onDataChange(data);
</script>
```

Comment: That code is working fine as your onclick there isn't being fired until *after* the window.mypage.onDataChange is defined.

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you, but as it turned out problem was bad php "if" statement, in some cases js script was unreachable!